# Issues Installing PHP Memcache module

Tags: php, memcached

I am trying to install memcache on my VPS. When I type

```
$ pecl install memcache
```

I get this error

```
checking whether the C compiler works... configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs.
If you meant to cross compile, use `--host'.
See `config.log' for more details.
ERROR: `/root/tmp/pear/memcache/configure --enable-memcache-session=yes' failed
```

Any ideas what the issue could be?

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be check what config.log says. Perhaps you don't have a compiler installed.

Comment: I am certain I have a compiler installed. I cannot seem to locate the config.log file or I would post that as well. A google search turned up nothing as to where it would be located. Thanks.

Comment: I suspect it would be in /root/tmp/pear/memcache/config.log.

Answer (score 0):

I had such an issue on iPhone, where compiled programs should be signed before they can be run. Make a small test: create a simple helloworld program `test.c`:

`#include 
main() {
    int number=42;
    printf("The answer is %i\n", number);

}`

And try to compile it: `gcc test.c -o test && ./test`

This should fail on your system (that's exactly what "cannot run C compiled programs" stands for!). Consult the on-screen errors and examine what's the reason for this.

Cheers!

Comment: signed? This is Linux, not iPhone. Or I have misunderstood what you've said.

Answer (score 0):

sudo pecl install memcache

Cheers